# BigQuery : GROUP BY include the non-aggregated column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's assume I have a table like follows:

```
| sku | date     | time  | inc_col| latest_col1 |latest_col2| 
+-----+----------+-------+--------+-------------+-----------+
|1    |2020-10-26| 08:00 | 100    | 10          |a          |
|1    |2020-10-26| 10:00 | -10    | 11          |b          |
|1    |2020-10-26| 06:00 | 5      | 7           |c          | 
|2    |2020-10-26| 08:00 | 300    | 4           |x          | 
|2    |2020-10-26| 10:00 |-100    | 4           |y          |
|2    |2020-10-26| 03:00 | 10     | 8           |z          |
```

Now this query will produce the following result:

```
SELECT sku,date,SUM(inc_col) from tbl GROUP BY sku,date
```

;

```
|sku |date       | inc_col|
+----+-----------+--------+
|1   |2020-10-26 |  105   |
|2   |2020-10-26 |  210   |
```

Is it possible to include the last value of 'latest_col1','latest_col2' ORDERED BY "time" column, as follows :

```
|sku |date      |inc_col|latest_col1| latest_col2|
+----+----------+-------+-----------+------------+
|1   |2020-10-26|   105 | 11        |   b        |
|2   |2020-10-26|   210 |  4        |   y        |
```

Is it possible to achieve this using any WINDOWING function?
This table has hundreds of columns of type 'inc_col' and 'latest_col' type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array functions are a simple way to do this:

```
SELECT sku, date, SUM(inc_col),
       ARRAY_AGG(latest_col1 ORDER BY time)[ORDINAL(1)] as latest_col1,
       ARRAY_AGG(latest_col2 ORDER BY time)[ORDINAL(1)] as latest_col1
FROM tbl
GROUP BY sku, date;
```

If fact, you can get the entire most recent *row* if you like:

```
SELECT sku, date, SUM(inc_col),
       (ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY time)[ORDINAL(1)]).* as latest_rec
FROM tbl t
GROUP BY sku, date;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use window function SUM to calculate inc_col and window function LAST_VALUE to find latest_col1, latest_col2:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT sku,
  date,
  SUM(inc_col) OVER (PARTITION BY sku, date) AS inc_col, 
  FIRST_VALUE(latest_col1) OVER (PARTITION BY sku, date ORDER BY time DESC) AS latest_col1,
  FIRST_VALUE(latest_col2) OVER (PARTITION BY sku, date ORDER BY time desc) AS latest_col2  
FROM tbl;
```

Comment: actually i dont want the MAX of latest_col1/latest_col2 ,rather the last value ordered by "time" column

Comment: I  agree, try this query,please

Comment: thank you. whats the syntax if i have more than one inc_cols ? like inc_col1,inc_col2..etc ?

Comment: Ashika Umanga Umagiliya, do you mean such as: sum(inc_col1)over(partition by sku,date), sum(inc_col2)over(partition by sku,date)?